# Python library for Reinforcement Learning which includes SAC with batch reinforcement learning

Tags: open-source, library, python

I'm looking for a Python library related to Reinforcement Learning with the following features:

1. Includes the Soft Actor Critic (SAC) algorithm
2. Allows for "batch reinforcement learning", meaning the possibility to train AND evaluate the policy completely offline, basing only on a pre-filled batch of experiences from the beginning, without further interaction with the environment
3. (Optional, but would be great) Includes SAC variant for hybrid action spaces (i.e. some actions are taken from a discrete space, some other action from a continuous space)

I don't know if such a library actually exists, but even a recommendation for a similar solution would be really welcome